Error[Pe020]: identifier is undefined in vector table for RTOS-based ADC Interrupt
I'm doing a training program for embedded development, and right now I'm working on setting up an ADC interrupt in an RTOS environment in IAR Embedded Workbench.
I'm running into a problem when I try to link the ADC interrupt to the AdcIsr function within the interrupt vector table. The instructions for the assignment says to replace (CPU_FNCT_VOID)BSP_IntHandler_102 on line 102, with (CPU_FNCT_VOID)AdcIsr
Here is the code for interrupts.c, which contains the interrupt vector table and their interrupt handlers:
#include  <bsp_cfg.h>
#include  <cpu.h>
#include  <os.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include  <cpu_core.h>
#include  <lib_def.h>
#include  <bsp_int_vect_tbl.h>
#include "adc.h"

/*
*********************************************************************************************************
*                                       INTERRUPT VECTOR TABLE
*
* Note(s): 1) Could be in RAM if BSP_CFG_INT_VECT_RAM_EN is set to 1 in 'bsp_cfg.h'
*          2) In either case BSP_IntVectSet() must becalled to boint to BSP_IntVectTbl[]
*
*********************************************************************************************************
*/

#if     BSP_CFG_INT_VECT_TBL_RAM_EN > 0u
static  CPU_FNCT_VOID  BSP_IntVectTbl[] =
#else
const   CPU_FNCT_VOID  BSP_IntVectTbl[] =
#endif
{
    (CPU_FNCT_VOID)BSP_IntHandler_000,              /*  00 */
    (CPU_FNCT_VOID)BSP_IntHandler_001,              /*  01 */
    (CPU_FNCT_VOID)BSP_IntHandler_002,              /*  02 */
    (CPU_FNCT_VOID)BSP_IntHandler_003,              /*  03 */
    // ... other interrupt handlers ...
    (CPU_FNCT_VOID)AdcIsr,                          /* 102 */
    // ... other interrupt handlers ...
};

Here is my header file:
#ifndef _ADC_H
#define _ADC_H

void  adc_task (void * p_arg);

#endif /* _ADC_H */

If relevant, here is my C code for the ADC:
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>             
#include <stdio.h>

#include "os.h"
#include "iorx63n.h"

#include "adc.h"
#include  <bsp_glcd.h>


// Message Queue for ISR->Task Communication
static OS_Q  g_adc_q;


#define ADC_SOURCE_VR1      2

#define ADC_INTERRUPT_AFTER_SCAN    0x10
#define ADC_START                   0x80

#define BIT(n)              (1 << (n))


// NOTE: Refer to p. 1,698 to 1,727  of Processor_UsersManual_Hardware.pdf
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t           control;                      // Offset 0x00
  uint8_t  const    _unused1[3];
  uint16_t          channel_select0;              // Offset 0x04
  uint16_t          channel_select1;              // Offset 0x06
  uint16_t          value_addition_mode_select0;  // Offset 0x08
  uint16_t          value_addition_mode_select1;  // Offset 0x0A
  uint8_t           value_addition_count_select;  // Offset 0x0C
  uint8_t  const    _unused2;
  uint16_t          control_extended;             // Offset 0x0E
  uint8_t           start_trigger_select;         // Offset 0x10
  uint8_t  const    _unused3;
  uint16_t          extended_input_control;       // Offset 0x12
  uint8_t  const    _unused4[6];
  uint16_t          temperature_sensor_data;      // Offset 0x1A
  uint16_t          internal_reference_data;      // Offset 0x1C
  uint8_t  const    _unused5[2];
  uint16_t          data[21];                     // Offset 0x20
} adc_t;

adc_t volatile * const p_adc = (adc_t *) 0x00089000;
#define adc     (*p_adc)


/*!
* @brief Configure the ADC hardware to read Potentiometer VR1 and interrupt.
*/
static void adc_config (void)
{
    /* Protection off */
    SYSTEM.PRCR.WORD = 0xA503u;            
    
    /* Cancel the S12AD module clock stop mode */
    MSTP_S12AD = 0;

    /* Protection on */
    SYSTEM.PRCR.WORD = 0xA500u;        

    // Select the 12-bit ADC. In the HW course, this detail is in BSP_Init().
    SYSTEM.MSTPCRA.BIT.MSTPA17 = 0;

    /* Use the AN000 (Potentiometer) pin 
       as an I/O for peripheral functions */
    PORT4.PMR.BYTE = 0x01;

    // Enable A/D interrupts at an appropriate priority, as instructed.
    uint8_t * p_IER = (uint8_t *)0x0008720C;
    uint8_t * p_IPR = (uint8_t *)0x00087366;

    *p_IPR = 9;                         // Set interrupt priority.
    *p_IER |= 0x40;                     // Unmask A/D interrupt.

    // Configure the A/D to perform a single scan and interrupt.
    adc.control = ADC_INTERRUPT_AFTER_SCAN;
    adc.channel_select0 = BIT(ADC_SOURCE_VR1);
}

/*!
*
* @brief: ADC Driver Task
*/
void adc_task (void * p_arg)
{
    OS_ERR     err;

    void *p_msg;
    OS_MSG_SIZE msg_size;
    uint16_t adc_value;
    char p_str[13];

    (void)p_arg;    // NOTE: Silence compiler warning about unused param.

    // Create message queue.
    // NOTE: It's safe to do this here, because the ISR is synchornized to us.
    OSQCreate(&g_adc_q, "ADC Queue", 1, &err);
    assert(OS_ERR_NONE == err); 

    // Configure ADC hardware to read Potentiometer VR1 and interrupt.
    adc_config();
    
    for (;;)    
    {
        // Wait 125 ms.
        OSTimeDlyHMSM(0, 0, 0, 125, OS_OPT_TIME_HMSM_STRICT, &err);
                                            
        // Trigger ADC conversion.
        adc.control |= ADC_START;
            
        // TODO: Wait for message from ISR, then format and display on LCD.;
        p_msg = OSQPend(&g_adc_q, 100, OS_OPT_PEND_BLOCKING, &msg_size, (void *)0, &err);
        adc_value = *(uint16_t*)p_msg;
        sprintf(p_str, "ADC: %4u", adc_value);
        BSP_GraphLCD_String(5, p_str);
    }
}

/*!
*
* @brief ADC Interrupt Handler
*/
void adc_isr (void)
{
    static uint16_t  sample;    // NOTE: Not on the stack; so address is valid.
    OS_ERR           err;

    // Read from the A/D converter and reduce the range from 12-bit to 10-bit.
    sample = adc.data[ADC_SOURCE_VR1] >> 2;
    
    // TODO: Send sample value to ADC task via a message queue
    OSQPost(&g_adc_q, &sample, sizeof(sample), OS_OPT_POST_FIFO + OS_OPT_POST_ALL + OS_OPT_POST_NO_SCHED, &err);
}

The assembly code containing the AdcIsr() function has already been provided to me. The instructions state that no changes need to be made within this file, but I will include it here for context:



    extern     _adc_isr
    extern     _OSIntExit
    extern     _OSIntNestingCtr
    extern     _OSTCBCurPtr

;/*$PAGE*/
;********************************************************************************************************
;                                             AdcIsr()
;********************************************************************************************************

    section .text:CODE:ROOT

    public  _AdcIsr

_AdcIsr:

    PUSHC   FPSW                        ; Save processor registers on the stack
    PUSHM   R1-R15
    MVFACHI R1
    MVFACMI R2
    PUSHM   R1-R2

    MOV.L   #_OSIntNestingCtr, R5       ; Notify uC/OS-III about ISR
    MOV.B   [R5], R3
    ADD     #1, R3
    MOV.B   R3, [R5]

    CMP     #1, R3                      ; if (OSNestingCtr == 1)
    BNE     _AdcIsr1
    MOV.L   #_OSTCBCurPtr, R5           ; Save current task's SP into its TCB
    MOV.L   [R5], R3
    MOV.L   R0, [R3]

_AdcIsr1  MOV.L   #_adc_isr, R5
    JSR     R5

    MOV.L   #_OSIntExit, R5
    JSR     R5                          ; Notify uC/OS-III about end of ISR

    POPM    R1-R2                       ; Restore processor registers from stack
    SHLL    #16, R2
    MVTACLO R2
    MVTACHI R1
    POPM    R1-R15
    POPC    FPSW

    RTE

    end


The exact errors I am getting are:
Error[Pe020]: identifier "AdcIsr" is undefined C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\Exercises\HandsOn\Exercise7\interrupts.c 158 

Error[Pe044]: expression must have pointer type C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\Exercises\HandsOn\Exercise7\interrupts.c 158 

Error while running C/C++ Compiler 

Within my header file (adc.h), I also tried to include the function like this:
#ifndef _ADC_H
#define _ADC_H

void  adc_task (void * p_arg);
extern void AdcIsr(void);

#endif /* _ADC_H */


Where is the declaration of AdcIsr() for the translation unit "interrupts.c"? This includes all included header files.

Please always provide complete error message. Is it from compiler or linker? Do you provide a prototype for AdcIsr somewhere?

@thebusybee I tried declaring AdcIsr() within my header file in various different ways and it did not work.

@Gerhardh The error message is with the compiler I am also getting the error "expression must have pointer type" in the same line not sure if it is relevant, though.

Please show how you tried to declare that function. Please add the complete and exact error message to the question. If the compiler does not know that symbol, it assumes it must be int which does not fit for assigning to a function pointer.

It might also be useful to show, how your compiler defines CPU_FNCT_VOID

@Gerhardh extern void AdcIsr(void); is how I am trying to declare the function (I also tried it without extern). the exact error message is this: Error[Pe020]: identifier "AdcIsr" is undefined C:\Users\MYNAME\OneDrive - COMPANY NAME\Desktop\Exercises\HandsOn\Exercise7\interrupts.c 158 and Error[Pe044]: expression must have pointer type C:\Users\MYNAME\OneDrive - COMPANY NAME\Desktop\Exercises\HandsOn\Exercise7\interrupts.c 158 .

As I mentioned: Please add it to the question. Comments are not suitable to hold code. Also please show where you tried to put that prototype.

Ok i added to the question

@Gerhardh I went into bsp_int_vect_tbl.h and changed the decleration of BSP_IntHandler_102 to AdcIsr and the error went away. But I am not sure if I was supposed to do that?

Oh my god nevermind it worked

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
